# jquery resend/request ajax if results not what i need

Tags: jquery

I have a table with 10 rows each row has a unique ID number in the first column, i use an ajax function to serve a php file that data mine a website based on the ID number, and then populates the cells on each row with the relevant data i want. However sometimes the website sends back blank results, so what i am wanting to do is, process that ID and AJAX function again. is this possible?

```
    var params = {};
    params['cmd'] = "2";
    params['asin'] = $("input[name=asin]").val();
    params['seller_id'] = seller_id;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'htmlpage-jsonarray.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        data: params
    }).done(function(data) {

        $data = $('<div/>').html(data.result);

        if(data.success) {

            var params1 = {};

            params1['stock1']       = $data.find('span[class=availGreen]').text();      // left in stock
            params1['stock2']       = $data.find('select[id="quantity"] option').length;        // max order at one time
            params1['delivery2']    = filterformat_delivery($data.find('span#pricePlusShippingQty span[class=plusShippingText]').text());       // shipping cost
            params1['price2']       = filterformat_price($data.find('span#actualPriceValue b[class=priceLarge]').text());       // selling for
            params1['seller_name']  = $data.find("#searchDropdownBox option:selected").text();

            $.each(params1, function(k, v) {
                    if (v == "") {
                        v = "*****";
                    }
                $("td[data-x='"+x+"'][data-field='"+k+"']").text(v);
            });

        };

    }).fail(function() {
        alert("2");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

If the following code doens't work, please comment **dataType: 'json'** and then **alert(data)** to check out PHP error

**JS**

```
var params = {};
params['cmd'] = "2";
params['asin'] = $("input[name=asin]").val();
params['seller_id'] = seller_id;
call_ajax();

function call_ajax() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'htmlpage-jsonarray.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        data: params,
        success : function(data) {

            $data = $('<div/>').html(data.result);

            if( data.success == 1 ) {

                var params1 = {};

                params1['stock1']       = $data.find('span[class=availGreen]').text();      // left in stock
                params1['stock2']       = $data.find('select[id="quantity"] option').length;        // max order at one time
                params1['delivery2']    = filterformat_delivery($data.find('span#pricePlusShippingQty span[class=plusShippingText]').text());       // shipping cost
                params1['price2']       = filterformat_price($data.find('span#actualPriceValue b[class=priceLarge]').text());       // selling for
                params1['seller_name']  = $data.find("#searchDropdownBox option:selected").text();

                $.each(params1, function(k, v) {
                    if (v == "") {
                        v = "*****";
                    }
                    $("td[data-x='"+x+"'][data-field='"+k+"']").text(v);
                });

            } else { 
                // wait 3 seconds then try again
                setTimeout(function(){
                    call_ajax();
                },3000);

            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.errorThrown);
            alert(data.textStatus);
            alert(data.jqXHR);
        }
    }
}
```

**PHP**

```
if ( $result != '' ) {

    $array['success'] = 1;
    $array['result'] = $result;
}
else {
    $array['success'] = 0;
    $array['result'] = '';
}

header('Content-Type: application/json'); // before echo
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Thanks Terry, i actually was looking to recall the function where the v=="" else but i just moved your example to that if else instead and works great so thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can make AJAX calls inside the .done() callback method. I recommend creating a reusable function that you can make the call instead of copy-pasting AJAX code.

Comment: do you have an example on how to do this, or able to point me towards resource page.

Comment: Check out this plunker: [http://plnkr.co/edit/QkN3mqVJml9dZSNJgohW](http://plnkr.co/edit/QkN3mqVJml9dZSNJgohW). It's an example of calling for data, check if there's issues and calling again, as well as having a fail fall back.

Comment: // Add your javascript here
$(function(){
  function getData (userId) {
    console.log('go');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.angel.co/1/users/' + userId,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
    })
    .done(processData)
    .fail(processError);
  }
  
  function processData (data) {
    if(!data.success) {
      getData(155);
    }
  }
  
  function processError (data) {
    console.log(data);
    
    // check for any specific error status if needed
      // call with desired data
    getData(155);
  }
  
  getData(-1);
});